# How to properly handle negative values on a line graph using react-native-svg

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, svg, expo

I'm having some trouble trying to process budget data to be charted on a line graph.  Using react-native-svg, the canvas runs from 0-300, with 150 representing the zero line. So everything above that line are positive numbers and below are negative numbers.

I can handle the data for the most part ok, but, it's actual math that is throwing me for a loop.

Sample data:

```
const Income = [200, 945, 1300, 1400];
const Expenses = [100, 900, 1400, 1200];
const Balance = [100, 45, -100, 200];
```

The first thing I do is normalize/scale the data into my 0-300 range, but I'm pretty sure I'm not doing it right.

Here is what I have so far:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ymqwvxyy69

You can see it kinda works, but I know that my math is not correct.

Does anyone have any guidance or suggestions on how to handle this data better, or more precisely, correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thats fine, just not displaying data for the current month yet.

Comment: I dont think the math is right.  For example, invert value, 160? Why 160? Such an arbitrary number that seems to make it look right.  It looks right with this current data set, but I highly doubt 160 is going to work for whatever I throw at it

Comment: Ah now i got you.

Comment: I just changed the data and it doesn't propagate, so I'll have to come up with a way to tweak that 160 dynamically as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are several things to be careful with.

1. It does not make sense to calculate min, max and the norm for each "line" separately
2. I would recommend using MinMax Scaling instead of Standardization
3. SVGs are using the image coordinate system, that's why you have to invert all your values

**MinMax Scaling:**

```
//calculate global absolute maximum. The maximum equals 150points 
const newGlobalArray = [ ...ylineIncome, ...ylineExpenses, ...ylineBalance]
    var absMax = newGlobalArray.reduce(function(max, item){
      return Math.max(Math.abs(max),Math.abs(item));
});
// Apply norm
const minMaxNorm = array => {
  let norm;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    norm = (array[i] / absMax) * 150;
    array[i] = norm;
  }
}
```

**Inverting:**

The image coordinate system starts with (y:0,x:0) in the top left (see image below). The coordinate system we expect has its origin in image coordinate system at point (y:150,x:0). So you can modify your `invertValue` function to:

```
const invertValue = value => {
  return (value * -1 + 150);
};
```

[image]

Here is the complete code: https://codesandbox.io/s/j72pyopp15

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'm glad to know I was 'close' with the math, as it's not my strong suit, and I understand what you've done.  I never would have arrived at MinMaxScaling on my own. I kinda understand what's happening with the newGlobalArray.  You reduce each line of data, but I'm a little fuzzy on `return Math.max(Math.abs(max),Math.abs(item));`